# Jquery append function won't work if decimals are included in data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I am making a simple shopping cart to learn HTML / JQUERY. You add the item name, id, price, etc. and it adds it into a shopping cart. I have a couple functions that create objects from the input fields and then appends it to a table. I noticed that if I have a decimal value as the item cost, it won't append the new row to the table. If it is an integer value it works fine.

HTML:

```
<form role="form" id="shoppingcart">
                <br style="clear:both">
                <h3 style="margin-bottom: 25px; text-align: center;">Purchase Item</h3>
                <!-- Div for date -->
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="date" class="form-control" id="date" name="date" placeholder="Date" required>
                </div>
                <!-- Div for Item ID -->
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="number" class="form-control" id="itemID" name="itemID" placeholder="Item ID" required>
                </div>
                <!-- Div for name -->
                <div class="form-group">

                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Name" required>
                </div>
                <!-- Div for description -->
                <div class="form-group">
                    <textarea class="form-control" type="textarea" id="description" name="description" placeholder="description" maxlength="25" rows="7"></textarea>
                </div>
                <!-- Div for quantity -->
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="number" class="form-control" id="quantity" name="quantity" placeholder="Quantity" required>
                </div>
                <!-- Div for unit price -->
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="number" class="form-control" id="unitPrice" name="unitPrice" placeholder="Unit Price" required>
                </div>
                <!-- div for cost -->
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="number" class="form-control" id="cost" name="cost" placeholder="Cost" disabled="disabled" required>
                </div>

                <label><span>&nbsp;</span><input class="addrow" type="submit" value="Add to Cart" /></label>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
```

JS:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    var mainElement = document.getElementById('shoppingCart');

//Serialization form to create object from inputs
function serializeForm() {
    var inputFields = $(mainElement).find('form :input');
    var result = {};
    $.each(inputFields, function (index, value) {
        if ($(value).attr('name')) {
            result[$(value).attr('name')] = $(value).val();
        }
    });
    return result;
}


$(mainElement).find('input[type="submit"]').click(function (evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
   if ($(evt.target).parents('form')[0].checkValidity()) {


        var shoppingItem = serializeForm();
        var html = '<tr><td>' + shoppingItem.itemID + '</td>' +
                   '<td>' + shoppingItem.name + '</td>' +
                   '<td>' + shoppingItem.description + '</td>' +
                   '<td>' + shoppingItem.quantity + '</td>' +
                   '<td>' + shoppingItem.unitPrice + '</td>' +
                   '<td class="cost">' + shoppingItem.cost + '</td></tr>'

        $('table tbody').append(html);
        $(mainElement).find('input[type="text"]').val('');

        //$(calculateSum);
    }

});
```

});

the calculateSum call is to another function that calculates shipping, total, tax costs and updates other input fields with them

Answer (score 0):

Turns out on checkValidation() input type of "number" returns as false if there is a decimal, including step="any" in the tag allowed decimal places to be used in that input and validate.

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify your div for cost to:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <input type="number" class="form-control" id="cost" 
  name="cost" placeholder="Cost" step="any" required>
</div>
```

Notice step="any" attribute value.

When you don't provide any value the value is incremented by 1. Even in any the value would get incremented by 1 but if you mention 3.2, it would increment to 4.2 etc.
Additional benefit is that this if condition would pass:

```
if ($(evt.target).parents('form')[0].checkValidity())
```

Looks like this is what you are looking for?